# How to (pg_)restore selected tables with all indexes?

Tags: postgresql, dump, restore

I would like to restore selected (currently after `-t`) tables including all indexes without making a definition after `-I` - because indexes are changing, new ones are created, old ones may expire.
What is the best way to perform the restore process in Postresql db?
I have read that is possible to restore whole db, and then delete unnecessary tabels.
I'm afraid that the process will be much longer and will load the database too much.

`-t` - recreates only data
`-I` - I have to define index by myself, I want it to happen automatically

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to do that is on the dump side.  With pg_dump, -t will dump the index definitions along with the table, while on the pg_restore side, -t won't include the indexes.

If you can't use -t on the pg_dump side of things, then I think you will need to script up something using the -l and -L flags to pg_restore.